# Finding the execution time of each step of a Spark stage

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How could I find the duration of each step in a Spark stage?

[image]

I'd like to figure out which step exactly is the bottleneck of my job.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the class **StreamingJobProgressListener** which is the default implementation of [StreamingListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/StreamingListener.html) by Spark for capturing job progress metrics.

This listener can be fetched as follows:

```
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkconf, Durations.seconds(60));
StreamingJobProgressListener progressListener =  jssc.ssc().progressListener();
```

You can explore the **progressListener.onStageSubmitted, progressListener.onStageCompleted, progressListener.onTaskStart** and **progressListener.onTaskEnd** functions for getting the metrics you required.

Comment: It seems that there is no alternative in the scala version. The progressListener is private https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.scala

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use Spark UI to get much performance metrics about specific transformations inside a stage such as map or flatMap because it is part of optimizations of pipeline operations in Spark.

You could however insert collect() action and timer between these transformations to simulate it.

Here is a post that could shed light on how one can use Spark UI to debug applications.
[Understanding your Apache Spark application through visualization](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html)